# Laravel + Redis и множественные теги

Tags: laravel, кэширование, redis

Мне необходимо кэшировать данные в Laravel с помощью redis, при этом одному массиву данных может соответствовать много тегов. Как это сделать? Не могу найти команду redis, которой можно так сделать, либо это возможности Laravel?

Comment: К сожалению такой встроенной возможности пока нет: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2668

Comment: А тег и ключ это одно и то же?

Comment: В данном случае - да. Вы хотите один массив получить используя разные ключи (я так понимаю без дублирования массива в памяти redis). Если возможно дублирование - то я не вижу никаких проблем.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы и ключи и теги были, это все-таки разные вещи, по-крайней мере так поставлено задание. Я новичок в laravel, потому не могу разобраться пока